# Union find algorithm pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, union-find

I don't understand something about **union find algorithm**.

Conceptually, I get how it works. I understand that if two items belong to different groups, then the two groups are merged into one. However, in the following pseudocode,

```
if rank[xSet] < rank[ySet]
```

then item `xSet` is set to `ySet`. That is, this item now belongs to the other group. But the thing is that all the items that are in group `xSet` should also be belonging to `ySet` now. This is not implemented in the pseudocode.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```py
function UNION(x, y)
    xSet ← FIND(x)
    ySet ← FIND(y)
    if xSet = ySet then
        return False       # Nothing to merge
    else if rank[xSet] < rank[ySet] then
        set[xSet] ← ySet
    else
        set[ySet] ← xSet
        if rank[xSet] = rank[ySet] then
            rank[xSet] ← rank[xSet] + 1
    return True
```

Comment: you should check find function it should be recursive

Comment: yes it is like that: if set[x] != x then set[x] = find(set[x]) return set[x]; I just cannot really understand what this does

Comment: I think it's called path compression or smth like that

Comment: The `union` function doesn't need to update other nodes in the `rank` and `set` arrays, because the `find` function knows that the `set` array isn't necessarily up-to-date, so it does a (usually very short) search to find the root node of the set, instead of just returning the element's parent node.

Comment: Okay. I think what it does is just make a chain of objects that belong to a group, but each object can be marked as not belonging to that certain group but linking to objects that actually belong to the group. So iterate through all these objects until we find a one that actually is from the group ( set[x] = x ), and set all objects' group: set[obj] = x. Am I correct? :)

Comment: No, it does belong to the group, it's just that the group is indicated by the root node (i.e. the end of the chain), not the parent node (immediate next element in the chain). You don't need to iterate over the rest of the group and set their parent to be their root node, because the `find` algorithm takes care of that if and when it needs to.

Comment: You say "all the items that are in the group `xSet` should also be belonging to `ySet` now", and that this is not implemented.  The set they belong to is whatever FIND returns.  Without seeing the FIND code we cannot verify that what you say is true, and I suspect that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you would go about actively modifying the set ownership of every element in a set, then union step will effectively take *O(max(#xset, #yset))* time. Further, you may not even query the elements whose set ownership you just modified, resulting in all that extra time simply going down the drain.

---

On the other hand, if you would only update the ownership of the parent element of the set, then this step is just O(1)! You saved a lot of time in not modifying all the individual elements. Next, when you have to find the ownership of any item, you traverse the parent over and over, until you finally find the element who has no parent and the owner of that item is the owner of the item you were initially looking for.

With that, you do not do any unnecessary work.

---

**Bonus:** In the process of traversing the parents, you can come back and correct the ownership of all the parent-elements that you encountered and update their set-ownership to the final value so that next time, not only this step is O(1) but a whole lot of other queries' run time is reduced.